# Add Image Array and text view in scrollView with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to add image and texts (under each image view) in ScrollView. 
 
 I add ScrollView firstly and add UIImage View. 
 But, I add two images in image array and it only appears one image when I run the app. Here is my code;

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

var imgArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "home_image"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "provider_image")]
```

and in ViewDidLoad() function,

```
 for index in 0 ..< imgArray.count
    {
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        debugPrint(index)
        imgView.image = imgArray[index]


    }
```

I also want to add each image caption under each image. How to do it? 
 Why only one image appear? :(

Comment: @NiravD, so bro Could you please show me the code of how should I edit?

Comment: If you want help then you need to first show us what you are trying the code you have added does nothing not even adding imgView as subView as you are telling so first add actual code that you are trying currently

Comment: I add scrollview and image view. I create outlet from UIimageView. @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView! . Then, I declare the image array. var imgArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "home_image"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "provider_image")] before ViewDidLoad. Inside ViewDidLoad, I add looping function.

Comment: I get that what I'm saying is if you want to show the multiple image you need to create multiple ImageView and that may be you are doing in for loop but there is no code of `view.addSubview(imgView)` to add `imgView` as subview in scrollView

Comment: I add this code " scrollView.addSubview(imgView) ". But, only one image appear bro.

Comment: If you want help then show the actual code that you are trying not some ex it is hard to predict where the problem is occur from current code

Comment: bro @NiravD, the above codes are currently I put in my swift file and running this. I have no idea of how to do it. This is actual code bro

Comment: @Have you added scrollView in storyboard? Because currently you are showing only one outlet and it is of imageView

Comment: Yes bro. I added and outlet it.

Comment: You want horizontal slider or vertical slider?

Comment: vertical slider and I want to add image caption under each image bro.

Comment: Then why don't you use tableView with customCell?

Comment: yeah... :D I think that is much better and easy to show. right? Thanks a lot bro Nirav. :D

Comment: Yes it is easy and best way. Simply add TableViewDataSource and delegate method and you all set to go

Comment: That's good and fastest way. :D Thanks a lot bro .

Comment: bro @NiravD, I would like to ask one question. I want to add background Image to Login page. So, should I need to make the all images size of launch screen? https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/   OR   when we add image in Image Assets, we create Image set. isn't it? In that place , there have 1x,2x and 3x images in Universal. So, should I only make that 3 sizes? Actually, login background image is not the launch screen image and I think I don' need to create all the image. How do you think bro?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let width = customScroll.frame.size.width
    for item in 1..<4{
        image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (CGFloat(item) * width - width), y: 10, width: width, height: 250))
        image.image = UIImage.init(named: "img"+String(item))
        customScroll.addSubview(image)
        print(image.frame)
    }
    customScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width * 4, height: 300)
```